# internal error; cannot instantiate <class>.<init>

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So I'm creating a program that has a class that takes about 20 variables (let's call this class Person). When I try to initialize the variable like so:

```
Person Steph = new Person(SName, SAge, SPhysical, SJob, SEducation, SPastSecret, SSecret1, Secret2, SSecret3, SConnections, SLikes, SHates, SCondtion, SNAME, SAGE, SPHYSICAL, SJOB, SEDUCATION, SPASTSECRET, SSECRET1, SECRET2, SSECRET3, SCONNECTIONS);
```

I get the error:

```
internal error; cannot instantiate Person.<init> at Person to
```

then lists the variable. Does anybody know what is causing this error?

EDIT: Here's the full code for Person:

```
class Person extends Detect{
public String Name, Age, Physical, Job, Education, PastSecret, Secret1, Secret2, Secret3, Connections, Likes, Hates, Condition;
public boolean NAME, AGE, PHYSICAL, JOB, EDUCATION, PASTSECRET, SECRET1, SECRET2, SECRET3, CONNETCTIONS, LIKES, HATES, CONDITION;

public Person(String Name, String Age, String Physical, String Job, String Education, 
String PastSecret, String Secret1, String Secret2, String Secret3, String Connections, String Likes, 
String Hates, String Condition, boolean NAME, boolean AGE, boolean PHYSICAL, boolean JOB, boolean EDUCATION,
boolean PASTSECRET, boolean SECRET1, boolean SECRET2, boolean SECRET3, boolean CONNECTIONS, 
boolean LIKES, boolean HATES, boolean CONDITION) {

    this.Name = Name;
    this.Age = Age;
    this.Physical = Physical;
    this.Job = Job;
    this.Education = Education;
    this.PastSecret = PastSecret;
    this.Secret1 = Secret1;
    this.Secret2 = Secret2;
    this.Secret3 = Secret3;     
    this.Connections = Connections;
    this.Likes = Likes;
    this.Hates = Hates;
    this.Condition = Condition;
    this.NAME = NAME;
    this.AGE = AGE;
    this.PHYSICAL = PHYSICAL;
    this.JOB = JOB;
    this.EDUCATION = EDUCATION;
    this.PASTSECRET = PASTSECRET;
    this.SECRET1 = SECRET1;
    this.SECRET2 = SECRET2;
    this.SECRET3 = SECRET3;
    this.CONNECTIONS = CONNECTIONS;
    this.LIKES = LIKES;
    this.HATES = HATES;
    this.CONDITION = CONDITION;

}



public void File(){
    System.out.printf("Suspect Name: %s         Age: %s       Appearance: %s\n", Check(NAME, Name), Check(AGE, Age),
        Check(PHYSICAL, Physical));
    System.out.printf("Job: %s          Education: %s           Past Secret: %s\n", Check(JOB, Job), Check(EDUCATION, Education), 
        Check(PASTSECRET, PastSecret));
    System.out.printf("Connections: %s    Secret: %s      Secret: %s    Secret: %s\n", Check(CONNECTIONS, Connections), Check(SECRET1, Secret1),
        Check(SECRET2, Secret2), Check(SECRET3, Secret3));
    System.out.printf("Likes: %s    Hates: %s    Conditions: %s\n\n", Check(LIKES, Likes), Check(HATES, Hates), Check(CONDITIONS, Conditions));
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the whole source code?

Comment: On a tangent; a method that takes 20 arguments is something that you should avoid...

Comment: please add the complete stack trace

Comment: Actually, the complete stack-trace would be more instructive.  By the way, this doesn't look like a compiler error (or failure) to me.

Comment: Is this error occurring during compile or when you attempt to run the application?  (The error is not a "compiler error" message.)

Comment: On another tangent; there are well-established naming conventions that you might like to follow (they help to make code clearer): Class names begin with capitals, variables begin with lowercase letters. So your code would be: `Person steph = new Person(sName, sAge, sPhysical, sJob ...);`

Comment: You're probably trying to run invalid code - count your (many) arguments and make sure you have the right amount/types, or check in an IDE (i.e eclipse) which should tell you something is wrong.

Comment: This error appears when I run javac <myprogram>.java in the command line.

Comment: One of my main goals coming back to this code is clean up, so thank you all for the tips!

Comment: On yet another tangent... having variables whose name differ merely by capitalisation is a tad confusing, especially when one is a String and the other is a Boolean.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing in 23 parameters to a constructor that has 26 parameters.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, do not make the class constructor to pass 20 variables. Create a POJO object and use it. For e.g:

```
public class Structure {
   private Object someObj;

   private Object someObj2;

   private Object someObj3;

   private Object someObj4;

   //getters and setters
}
```

And before sending it to `Person` class constructor set the needed variables through setter methods and pass just this `Structure` class. (This makes your code more efficient and more readable for worldwide community and your self.)

About the initialization. Are you sure that `Person` class' constructor is accepting all 20 variables? I am pretty sure that your `Person` class constructor is wrong. Try this way and this should work.

Answer (score 1):

`Person.<init>` refers to the constructor of the Person class.

The error says that the constructor for the Person class does not match the parameters that you are supplying. Unfortunately it doesn't tell you why not.

You might like to download and install an integrated development environment (IDE) such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). It will give you much more information about programming problems like this, and makes coding a lot easier.